# How can I initialize a collection of DateTime objects in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datetime, collections, datepicker

I have a validation class that needs to take a series of dates within a `List<DateTime>` collection that is provided as a property on the validator.

For some instances of this validator, I would like to populate dates within the XAML code, rather than from the code behind the window.  Specifically, I might need to populate the date `DateTime.Now` into the collection.

How can I do this?  Here is some code for one of my `DatePicker` controls that needs to use this implementation.

```
... Within a DatePicker control declaration ...
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <vr:DatePickerValidator Comparator="GreaterThanOrEqual" >
        <vr:DatePickerValidator.ComparisonDates>
            <!-- How can I insert a date for "DateTime.Now", rather than a hard-coded date? -->
        </vr:DatePickerValidator.ComparisonDates>
    </vr:DatePickerValidator>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use static classes inside property element children. However, you can do something like this

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <vr:DatePickerValidator Comparator="GreaterThanOrEqual" >
        <vr:DatePickerValidator.ComparisonDates>
           <x:Static MemberType="system:DateTime" Member="system:DateTime.Now"  />
           <x:Static MemberType="system:DateTime" Member="system:DateTime.Now"  />
           <x:Static MemberType="system:DateTime" Member="system:DateTime.Now"  />
        </vr:DatePickerValidator.ComparisonDates>
    </vr:DatePickerValidator>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

Comment: Will this work since ComparisonDates is a collection?  Also, how would I add multiple dates?  Consider the scenario where both `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)` need to be added.  How could this be done?

Comment: Do you own the `DatePickerValidator`? If that's the case. Yes you can. However, you cannot use AddDays(1). You have to extend it to accept certain stuff to invoke from behind the code.

Comment: Yes, I own the class.  I just wanted to know how to initialize multiple dates since this is a generic validator that I've developed for date selection.

Comment: I'd say use a `MVVM` pattern and just bind `ComparisonDates` to be bound to a static class that you can initialize. Much easier than doing it in XAML. Let the consumer of that class set it through code and not in XAML. It's more work on what you want to achieve, you might have to use custom markup language to achieve multiple date times instantiated in XAML.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work.  I'm getting an exception stating that my DateTime object couldn't be converted to a `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.DateTime]` object, which is what I suspected.

Comment: I understand, but the reason why I was hoping to do this in XAML is because some of these properties need to be set to "today" or within a week of "today".

Comment: It won't, I assumed your CD is DateTime only.

Comment: `ComparisonDates` is a `List<DateTime>` object, though I can define it to something more easily consumable, so long as it give me the same functionality of a collection.

Comment: @RLH Actually, try what my edit is. However, you still can't achieve AddDays(1)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this didn't work.  I Keep getting an "...'Now' is not a member of of the target type." error.  I also tried the "Today" member, and it gives the same error.  This is odd, cause you can certainly define a static date from within an attribute.  I've done that before. I just assumed there was a way to do like you've tried to provide.  Alas, I can get it to work, and I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it and it works. Make sure you are calling the class again on Member. Make sure it's `DateTime.Now` not just `Now`

Comment: I did do that, first.  It didn't work.  Then I dropped the "DateTime." in the member, and I continued to get the same error message.

Comment: Yes.  In my case it is defined as `sys` by the definition `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`.  So I tried to use `<x:Static MemberType="sys:DateTime" Member="sys:DateTime.Now"  />`

Comment: Against what? Try it with a simple case like `DatePicker`'s `SelectedDate`. I doubt it would perfectly work with your class, might need more work to make it work.